# Could you make a entire software with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, software-design

Javascript is a really good web-dev language, and it's also not bad at programming the backend side of websites. So is there a way to make software out of it?

Comment: Yes. E.g. [Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode) is predominantly TypeScript (which is JavaScript but with types).

Comment: Yes you can....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, software is just a collection of instructions that tell a computer how to work. As you stated, JavaScript is commonly used in building a website, whether the front-end or the back-end, and that is absolutely considered as a software, so yes, you can build software with JavaScript.

If you are referring to installable applications instead of websites, you can use React Native to build mobile applications, and Electron to build desktop applications. Both of them uses JavaScript.